# Show real time data without manually refreshing page

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using Google Maps. In a map I am displaying data from the backend API using AWS api-gateway. I am using aws-serverless-express library for this task and I want to auto-refresh the map data when data changes in backend.

How can I achieve this? I have tried out pubnub and socket but they didn't fulfill my requirements. I want to send back the response back to client only when data changes in backend. Until that time request will be on hold so I am little bit confused in these so please help me

Currently I have no code because I am confused how can I achieve this.

Comment: At first tought sockets seems to be the perfect solution for your needs, can you explain more precisely with it is not the case ?

Comment: yes i thought we can use sockets but wit that also we have to hit api's on a regular interval for getting updated data right?

Comment: What triggers the need for a map update within your back end server?